# Developer Express Suite old version download

Tags: devexpress

Can anyone tell me where I can download DevExpress 13.1.11.0 and  DevExpress 15.2.10.0 ?
If I want to work with trial version the web site download manager seems to allow only the download of the 
latest version.
Thanks in advance for helping me.
Simone

Comment: Trial versions are not available for out-of-date product versions. As mentioned by @Dom Sinclair, you may only download previous versions under a registered account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to your account on the DevExpress website.  Once logged in look for the 'My Downloads' ling at the top right of the page. Click on that and you'll be taken to the downloads page.

Select the subscription that applies to you and then from the dropdown box next to it select the version that you want to download.  By default it will always show the latest available subscription however all of the previous versions are available there as well.

Hope that helps